# Placing two separate figures side by side

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, templates, figure-placement

Suppose I have two separate figures in separate Tex files and I use \input{tex file of figure} to include the two figures in the main Tex.file of a two colomn template article assume the two tex files of the figures are:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\scalebox{1}{\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth]{model1.png}
\end{overpic}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\footnotesize Fig.}
      \caption{\footnotesize (a) Model 1.}
       \vspace{-2.6mm}
          \label{fig1}
    \end{figure}
```

and the second figure:

```
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    
    \scalebox{1}{\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth]{model2.png}
    \end{overpic}}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{\footnotesize Fig.}
          \caption{\footnotesize (b) Model 2.}
           \vspace{-2.6mm}
              \label{fig1}
        \end{figure}
```

Now I want to make the two figures side by side in the whole width of the paper in this two column article template. For example at the top of the page with a general caption for both figures, something like:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\input{model1}
\input{model2}
\caption{for both figures}
\label{fig}
\end{figure*}
```

but it is not working

Comment: This sounds a lot like using `subfigure`, but with extra steps. Perhaps [this](https://latex-tutorial.com/subfigure-latex/) might help?

Comment: To post code examples of the quality we'd like to see here I invite you to follow these steps: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790